# Remove NA when using "order"

Tags: r

I have this huge matrix of data with columns for year, month, day and precipitation which I need to order and also delete the row when the precipitation is NA (which happens on the day 31 of every month that only has 30 days and Februaries...). After consulting the r help files I used the following code:

```
dat<- aa[order(aa$year, aa$month, aa$day, na.last=NA),]
```

It ordered my data perfectly but I still have all the NAs... Can anyone tell me why it hasn't work?

thanks

```
> head(dat)
    code year month                  station ALTITUD   PROV LONGITUD LATITUD day P1 id
1.1 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   1  0  1
1.2 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   2  0  1
1.3 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   3  0  1
1.4 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   4  0  1
1.5 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   5  0  1
1.6 3059 1940    11 ALBALATE DE LAS NOGUERAS     855 CUENCA   216372  402200   6  0  1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Are you sure they are true NA's?. Cpuld they be character strings or factors masquerading as NA's. What does sum(is.na(aa$day)) return?

Comment: The head() tells us nothing. We need dput() on rows of data that have things that look like NA's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `na.last` argument to `order` only removes `NA` from the objects passed to `order` via `...`.  Your `NA` are in `aa$precipitation`, not `aa$year`, `aa$month`, or `aa$day`, so you need:

```
dat <- na.omit(aa[order(aa$year, aa$month, aa$day),])
```

You may want to consider using a time-series class like zoo or xts for time-series data.

Answer (score 3):

Because `na.last` is to see if `NA` should be last of first when ordering not to remove the `NA`. Use `na.omit(dat)` to remove the `NA`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Except `?order` says, "na.last: ... if 'NA', they are removed."

Comment: na.last=NA _should_ remove the NA's. Something else is the cause of his problem.

Comment: I believe that this statement is incorrect.  The help file for `?order` states that `na.last=NA` can be used exactly as the OP did, i.e. to remove NA values.